# Can I convert for loop number pattern to while loop and do while loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I'm learning java looping, and managed to print a number one pattern using the for loop.
I tried printing the number one pattern using the while and do while loop, but had difficulty. This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
        if ((i == 0 && j > 1) || (i == 1 && j > 0) || (i == 2 && j >= 0) || (i == 3 && j > 1) || (i > 3 && j > 1))
            System.out.print("1");
        else
            System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

This is my while loop code:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (i <= 7) {
            while (j <= 4) {
                if((i == 0 && j > 1) || (i == 1 && j > 0) || (i == 2 && j >= 0) || (i == 3 && j > 1) || (i > 3 && j > 1))
                    System.out.print("1");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");

                j++;
            }

            System.out.println();
            i++;
        }
```

[image: this is my pattern]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to reset `j` counter after first `j_while` end

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
while (i <= 7)
{
//could also reset here
j=0;
    while (j <= 4)
    {
     if((i == 0 && j > 1) || (i == 1 && j > 0) || (i == 2 && j >= 0) || (i == 3 && j > 1) || (i > 3 && j > 1))
         System.out.print("1");
     else
         System.out.print(" ");
         j++;
     }
       System.out.println();
       i++;
 }
```

Comment: glad to be helpful, also if you were so kind could mark as solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any for loop can be converted into a while or do-while.

For example:

```
for(initialize; condition_check, statement1) {
    ......
}
```

Here `statement1`   =>  generally this is an `increment` or `decrement` of a variable used in the condition_check

Similarly the equivalent while loop would be:

```
initialize;
while (condition_check) {
     .......;
     statement1;
}
```

So it seems that you have forgotten to initialize one of the variables. The other answer has already given you that.

This answer would help in mapping the `for` loop to the `while` loop and vice-versa.

Hope it helps.